# Get reference to a component instance in its custom methods

Tags: javascript, extjs, scope

I want to extend an ext component and add several custom methods to it.

My question is: **When defing component how I can get reference to its instance  in its custom methods?** (check code below for clarification)

*As I understand with Ext.define I create somewhat like a class and with Ext.create (or via using of widget shortcut) I make objects of this class, correct me if I understand it wrong.*

As example:

I want to create page header component based on `Ext.toolbat.Toolbar`:

```
Ext.define('Ext.lib.extensions.MyPageHeader', {
    extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',
    alias: 'widget.myPageHeader',

    items: [
        xtype: 'component',
        autoEl: {
            cls: 'portal_page_header_title',
            tag: 'span'
        },
        id: 'pageTitleComponent'
    ],

    initComponent: function () {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.initialConfig, 'pageTitle')) {
            this.setPageTitle(this.initialConfig.pageTitle);
        }

        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    setPageTitle: function (title) {
        // How I can get reference to a MyPageHeader instance here?
        // Is seems that `this` doesnt work, atleast I cant use `down()` method of Ext.toolbar.Toolbar
        this.down('#pageTitleComponent').update(title);
    }
});
```

Workign solution for me is:

```
Ext.define('Ext.lib.extensions.MyPageHeader', {
    extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',
    alias: 'widget.myPageHeader',

    initComponent: function () {
        this.pageTitleComponent = Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
            autoEl: {
                cls: 'portal_page_header_title',
                tag: 'span'
            }
        });

        var pageHeaderItems = [
            this.pageTitleComponent
        ];

        Ext.apply(this, {
            items: pageHeaderItems
        });

        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.initialConfig, 'pageTitle')) {
            this.setPageTitle(this.initialConfig.pageTitle);
        }

        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    setPageTitle: function (title) {
        this.pageTitleComponent.update(title);
    }
});
```

But I dont think its best way to do such a thing. Is there better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will update the Page title

```
        Ext.define('Ext.lib.extensions.MyPageHeader', {
        extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar',
        alias: 'widget.myPageHeader',



        initComponent: function () {

            var me = this;

            Ext.applyIf(me, {

                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'component',
                        autoEl: {
                            cls: 'portal_page_header_title',
                            tag: 'span'
                        },
                        itemId: 'pageTitleComponent'
                    }
                ],
            });

            me.callParent(arguments);

            me.setPageTitle(me.pageTitle);
        },

        setPageTitle: function (title) {

            // How I can get reference to a MyPageHeader instance here?
            // Is seems that `this` doesnt work, atleast I cant use `down()` method of Ext.toolbar.Toolbar
            this.down('#pageTitleComponent').update(title);
        }
    });


    var cmp = Ext.create('Ext.lib.extensions.MyPageHeader', {
        pageTitle: 'Cool Cat Dog'
    });

    console.log(cmp.down('#pageTitleComponent').html); // Cool Cat Dog
```

See Updated Fiddle: 
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/11ld

The problem was that this.setPageTitle was called before this.callParent. Calling this.callParent adds all extended functionality including querying components.

good Luck!